# show a sidebar for category

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

I'm use giga-store template y wanna show in a sidebar all my categories.
I have a permalink call 'categoria'.(e.g. www.web.com/categoria/clean-products)

this is the function on category.php

```
function get_categories( $args = '' ) {
    $defaults = array( 'taxonomy' => 'category' );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

$taxonomy = $args['taxonomy'];

/**
 * Filters the taxonomy used to retrieve terms when calling get_categories().
 *
 * @since 2.7.0
 *
 * @param string $taxonomy Taxonomy to retrieve terms from.
 * @param array  $args     An array of arguments. See get_terms().
 */
$taxonomy = apply_filters( 'get_categories_taxonomy', $taxonomy, $args );

// Back compat
if ( isset($args['type']) && 'link' == $args['type'] ) {
    /* translators: 1: "type => link", 2: "taxonomy => link_category" alternative */
    _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '3.0.0',
        sprintf( __( '%1$s is deprecated. Use %2$s instead.' ),
            '<code>type => link</code>',
            '<code>taxonomy => link_category</code>'
        )
    );
    $taxonomy = $args['taxonomy'] = 'link_category';
}

$categories = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

if ( is_wp_error( $categories ) ) {
    $categories = array();
} else {
    $categories = (array) $categories;
    foreach ( array_keys( $categories ) as $k ) {
        _make_cat_compat( $categories[ $k ] );
    }
}

return $categories;
```

}
i put this in sidebar.php

```
$show=get_categories();
print_r(array_values($show));
```

but the results :(

```
Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 1 [name] => Sin categoría [slug] => sin-categoria [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 1 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 1 [category_count] => 1 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Sin categoría [category_nicename] => sin-categoria [category_parent] => 0 ) )
```

Help please

Comment: You are obviously getting something back. So how does this response differ from what you expected to see?

Comment: I wanna see all the categories in a sidebar, but im a new in wordpress, could you help me, perhaps i know how to register a new sidebar and define his columns.